# How to put components on the PWA splash screen in React

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I am in the process of converting a web app developed with React into a PWA.
In the process, splash screen is being implemented, but there is a component that has been created as splash screen in advance. Is there any way to use that component instead?

Answer (score 0):

no, you cannot use React Component as a splash screen, but you can customize the splash screen in the manifest.json file. and for IOS you can add image as the splash screen `<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image"  href="/apple-launch-splash-screen.png">`